# std::vector resize algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I'm actually trying to implement a simple copy of std::vector. During my tests to see if my data is consistent by comparing with the original one I noticed something.

```
std::vector<std::string> *v = new std::vector<std::string>(2);
std::string str1("Hello");
std::string str2("World");

v->push_back(str1);
v->push_back(str2);

v->resize(5);

for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = v->begin(); it != v->end(); it++)
{
    std::cout << "/" << (*it) << "/" << std::endl;
}
```

here is the result :

```
//
//
/Hello/
/World/
//
```

Can someone explain me why resize doesn't append std::string()'s like this :

```
/Hello/
/World/
//
//
//
```

What is the algorithm behind?

Comment: What did you see when you debugged your program in the debugger?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key is here:

```
std::vector<std::string> *v = new std::vector<std::string>(2);
```

This creates a vector with **2** elements, which are default-constructed (meaning - two empty strings). Then you `push_back` `Hello` and `World`. Now you have 4 elements. Then the `resize( 5 )` adds just one more element (also default-constructed).

I guess you wanted to manipulate/increase the capacity? You need `std::vector::reserve` instead.

---

You should create an empty vector and then use `push_back`s to see the behavior, you expect. Or just use `operator[]` instead of the two `push_back`s.

---

Is there a really good reason to create the vector on the heap, instead of on the stack? You (almost?) always should avoid this.

Comment: thank you so much I just didn't understand how the constructor work, i thought that the constructor just increase the capacity in this case.

Comment: @ClémentJean - if you want to increase the capacity, you need `std::vector::reserve`.

Comment: for the creation on the stack, I just want to copy the behavior of std::vector

Comment: @ClémentJean - this should not be relevant - the behavior of `std::vector` is the same in both cases. You should usually use it on the stack, there are extremely rare cases (which I can't think of now), when you may need to allocate it on the heap. Anyway, I'm glad that I helped.

Answer (score 1):

You are constructing a std::vector with 2 items inside, default constructed.
Reference: [std::vector constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

Replace:

```
std::vector<std::string> *v = new std::vector<std::string>(2);
```

with:

```
std::vector<std::string> *v = new std::vector<std::string>();
```

And, by the way, why are you allocating the vector on the heap with new?
Just declare it as:

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the construction of vector you passed `2` as argument. If you take a look at that construction you will see this:

```
explicit vector(size_type _Count)
```

Here you are creating a vector with two default constructed string in it and then push two other string into vector.
Use default construction and then use `std::vector::reserve` to increase the capacity of vector.

Answer (score 1):

To get the result that you are wanting to see, try the following:

```
std::vector<std::string> *v = new std::vector<std::string>({"s1","s2"});
```

Then go about your resizing and looping. This should give you the expected padding as you have suggested.